# Display number of spaces

Tags: string

How should I display the number of words contained in a string(vector)?
There may be multiple spaces between two words.

Ex: Input: ' Hello World,  How  are you ' should return 5.

To count the number of spaces in a vector v, I write:
n←+/v∊' '

But, it won't display the number of words.
Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s←'Hello world, how are you?'
a←s∊'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
+/ (a,0)∧~0,a
```

`a` is a vector which contains 1-s at the positions where letters occur and 0-s elsewhere.

```
s:   H e l l o   w o r l d ,   h o w   a r e   y o u ?
a:   1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Every initial letter of a word will correspond to a 1 preceded by a 0 (or in an initial position).  Well, if we shift this sequence to the right, negate it, and "and" it to the original value of `a`, we can identify word-initial letters:

```
s:           H e l l o   w o r l d ,   h o w   a r e   y o u ?
a,0:         1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
~0,a:        1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
(a,0)∧~0,a:  1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Now, counting the words is as easy as summation: `+/`

You can try the code with my interpreter at http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/index.html#code=s%u2190%27Hello%20world%2C%20how%20are%20you%3F%27%0Aa%u2190s%u220A%27abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%27%0A+/%28a%2C0%29%u2227%7E0%2Ca  or with http://tryapl.org

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar, but the trick is to deliberately add a space before the sentence and count only spaces that fall before a letter. In that way, the number of spaces equals the words, and you don't need to worry about trimming the text before performing the operation.

If I hadn't added the space (in the second line), I would have no way of knowing if the text had any leading spaces or not, so I would have to somehow check for that. By deliberately adding a space, I'm streamlining the text so that I know that I'm always dealing with at least one leading space.

**Count words:**

```
P←"My     cat  doesn't like    fishy  tasting     food.   "
L←' '⍷' ',P
+/L∧~1⌽L
```

Output:

```
7
```

**Get rid of unnecessary spaces:**

On a related subject, the value of `L` can also be used to trim spaces from the front and end of text and remove superfluous spaces:

```
1↓(L⍲1⌽L)/' ',P
```

Output:

```
"My cat doesn't like fishy tasting food."
```

**Trim leading and trailing spaces:**

If you want to trim the beginning and end of the text without removing superfluous spaces:

```
((∧\L)⍱⌽∧\⌽L)/' ',P
```

However, in this last one, it's not necessary to add the leading space. So, if you don't need to calculate `L` for any other reason, here's an alternative using `L2`:

```
L2←" "⍷P
((∧\L2)⍱⌽∧\⌽L2)/P
```

Output (same as in the beginning, but the extra spaces at the end are gone):

```
"My     cat  doesn't like    fishy  tasting     food."
```